# Closed form of the integral $\int \sin^2(x) x^p \frac{\log(x)^q}{1+\log(x)^q}$

Tags: integration

I have a pretty complicated integral I wish to find it (if possible) via a closed form.

It is completely expressible with elementary functions, but I have a feeling (having tried change of variables etc ) that this just might not have closed solution? Any suggestions welcome - thanks!

$$\int \sin^2(x) x^p \frac{(\log(x))^q}{1+(\log(x))^q}dx$$

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ positive integers? In general I think a fraction involving both powers of $x$ and trig functions of $x$ does not have a closed form, throw in some log on top and it looks fairly hopeless.

Comment: p,q are positive rational

Comment: I was trying contour integration but got nowhere fast...

Comment: Actuallly, $x^p sin^2(x)$ does have a closed form in terms of gamma functions

Comment: @MKF Integral given in books or asked in exams are surely solvable by hand, But other integrals may or may not be solva\ble. If you have encountered this one in a book or in an exam, please do mention this.

Comment: Mathematica give us $\dfrac{\sin ^2 x^{p+2} (x \log )^q \,
   _2F_1\left(1,\frac{p+q+2}{q};\frac{p+2}{q}+2;-(\log 
   x)^q\right)}{p+q+2}$

Comment: I think that is because you used the index on the log inside the log; really the integral has the index outside the log...

Comment: For info This integral is not in any textbook